# ddrescue won't resume even with log file

Tags: ddrescue

I did a partial gddrescue run with the log file. It's from one external USB disk to another.

> sudo ddrescue /dev/sda /media/myname/volume5/backup.dmg /media/myname/volume5/logfile.log

I stopped it midway, turned off my computer, unplugged the disks, and when I started again the disks were plugged in different ports and were at different mount points. The log file is still there and my backup image file is 300GB of a 500GB disk. They're just at different mount points. So I do the following with the new mount points:

> sudo ddrescue /dev/sdd /media/myname/volume4/backup.dmg /media/myname/volume4/logfile.log

The process still starts from scratch. What gives? The funny thing is that on the second run ddrescue may say that it has only rescued 50MB but the backup image is still sitting at 300GB. Is it just writing over the 300GB image file?

Comment: How did you stop it?

Comment: Just Ctrl+c which is the normal way, right?